I can't assembler a 16 bits in MASM
I'm studying 16-bit assembly. Now I'm learning how to write code in different files and then use the linker to join them into a .COM executable.
I followed the tutorial step by step in the book I'm reading but when I set it up with MASM it says that the symbol was not defined.
In the book I'm reading, the professor says that it is necessary to use the word PUBLIC in the definition of a routine to inform the linker that this routine can be called by codes in different files.
Below is the code I'm trying to assemble in MASM. It's a simple routine that prints the letter 'A' and exits.
;CODIGO.asm
CODE_SEG SEGMENT PUBLIC
ASSUME CS:CODE_SEG 

PUBLIC ROUTINE_1 
    
MOV AH,02H
MOV DL,41H
INT 21H 

ROUTINE_1 ENDP

CODE_SEG ENDS
 ENDS

....
; Output of MASM

C:\DOCUME~1\pedro>MASM.EXE CODE; 
The Microsoft MACRO Assembler
Version 1.10, Copyright (C) Microsoft Inc. 1981,82

?End of file encountered on input file
                                PUBLIC ROUTINE_1
 E r r o r   ---        9:Symbol not defined
                                ROUTINE_1 ENDP
 E r r o r   ---        0:Block nesting error
?End of file encountered on input file

Warning Severe
Errors  Errors
0       2

C:\DOCUME~1\pedro>D:\CODE.asm


I tried to insert after 'PUBLIC ROUTINE_1' the 'PROC NEAR' directives but it didn't work

Try ROUTINE_1 PROC PUBLIC instead.

Or two separate lines ROUTINE_1 proc and public ROUTINE_1

@ecm Thank you very much for working with the tip you gave. thanks

Wow - Nostalgia!  I haven't used masm 1.x since 1983. (The market for optimized 16-bit programs isn't what it used to be...)
